# Lighttpd localy serving FastCGI with forwarding all request to other sever at same time

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, lighttpd, supervisord

I'm working on **FastCGI** which generally serves images.

I have it on production with **Lighttpd**. It worked OK but I needed to add new features. A new version of **FastCGI** runs with **Nginx** and **Supervisord**. It generally works too but after some time (sometimes once per day, sometimes once per week) it stops to respond - all processes are on, but simply don't return anything. I switched production to old **FastCGI** with **Lighttpd**.

So I have to debug new version deeply with real traffic but I don't want to do it on production. Is there any way how to serve all requests on **Lighttpd** with local **FastCGI** (as it generally works now) but together with forwarding of all traffic to a different server at the same time? Some kind of proxy?

Comment: Sorry, lighttpd does not have a feature which both handles the request as FastCGI **and** proxies the request.  In your case, the request can be handled by either mod_fastcgi or by mod_proxy, but not by both.  What is the difference in "old" FastCGI and "new" FastCGI?  Perhaps you can upgrade lighttpd to the latest version (lighttpd 1.4.45) and see if that also works for you.

Comment: Thank you for comment, I afraid that there is no way. The differences in FastCGI are many (generally a new major version). Maybe a replication of traffic on CDN side would be the solution.